# Guard location of moving object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to have function, which guard location of moving object and when is location of node on some position, run an action. And call this function only for as long as there will be 10 times run action. (10 times move with moving object)

I try write something but I know that it will work only when I touch button and object must be on y = 0:

```
func touchButton1(){
    if object.position.y == 0 && object.isHidden == false{
        object.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 100, duration: 1))
    }
    return
}
```

So how to guard moving object? And how to guard it only for ten times run action.

I hope I wrote it understandable.

Comment: Do you mean the swift `guard` statement? Your grammar is confusing.

Comment: Just a note, unless you specifically coded the node to be at point 0 or move to point 0, testing for exactly 0 will probably not work.

Comment: sorry for my bad english ... maybe it is not word "guard", maybe "watch" is the right word. I have moving object from y= 1000 to y= -1000 .  If I touch button, I want to call function which will be watch position of moving object and when will be position of object y = 0, then run action. Is it possible?